# mysql replace a character with another

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table with some values like below,

```
Slno
---------
IFAAA1121
IFAAA1122
IMBBB1121
IMBBB11223
```

My goal is to reformat the SlNo in to the below format,

```
Slno
---------
IF-AAA-1121
IF-AAA-1122
IM-BBB-1121
IM-BBB-11223
```

How is it possible ?

My query is:

```
UPDATE `certificate_log_uae` 
SET `DeviceSerialNumberTemp` = REPLACE(LEFT(DeviceSerialNumberTemp,2),
                                       LEFT(DeviceSerialNumberTemp,2).'-')
```

Comment: @negative voter : why negative vote ???

Comment: SO community behaves weirdly sometimes. I feel that question is well phrased. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use the [`Substr()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) function to get substrings out from your input string, at various positions and lengths.
- Since the length of the last substring is not fixed; we can simply specify the start position to slice the substring, and leave specifying the length parameter. It will consider the substring till the end of the overall string.
- Now, just [concatenate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) this substrings back using `-` appropriately.

Try the following:

```
UPDATE `certificate_log_uae` 
SET `DeviceSerialNumberTemp` = CONCAT(SUBSTR(`DeviceSerialNumberTemp`, 1, 2), 
                                      '-', 
                                      SUBSTR(`DeviceSerialNumberTemp`, 3, 3), 
                                      '-', 
                                      SUBSTR(`DeviceSerialNumberTemp`, 6)
                                     )
```

Comment: but the length of the last part is not fixed

Comment: Thanks, its worked. can you please say why the neagtive vote get for my question

Comment: @JIJOMONK.A I have +1ed; questions seems to be well phrased; but only the person who downvoted can explain.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for the support.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to just build the final string you want using concatenation:

```
UPDATE certificate_log_uae
SET DeviceSerialNumberTemp = CONCAT(LEFT(DeviceSerialNumberTemp, 2),
                                    '-',
                                    SUBSTRING(DeviceSerialNumberTemp, 3, 3),
                                    '-',
                                    SUBSTRING(DeviceSerialNumberTemp, 6));
```

[image]

### Demo

If you are using MySQL 8+ or later, then there is a very simple regex based solution using `REGEXP_REPLACE`:

```
SELECT
    DeviceSerialNumberTemp,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(DeviceSerialNumberTemp, '(.{2})(.{3})(.*)', '$1-$2-$3') AS output
FROM certificate_log_uae;
```

### Demo

Comment: but the length of last part is not fixed.

Comment: Thanks, its worked. can you please say why the neagtive vote get for my question

Comment: Okay, Thank you for the support.

Answer (score 0):

Try simple `insert` function:

```
select Slno, insert(insert(slno, 3, 0, '-'), 7, 0, '-') from tbl
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gTBSXRk7pTD2D81VnfCL4/0)

To update values try:

```
update certificate_log_uae set
DeviceSerialNumberTemp = insert(insert(DeviceSerialNumberTemp , 3, 0, '-'), 7, 0, '-')
```

Comment: I dont want to select the data, i need to update the column values